# Maximize Function for Adjacent Crops; Garden Optimization Problem

Tags: python, math, optimization, maximize

Imagine a small garden, divided into 8 equal parts, each a square foot. The garden is 4 ft x 2 ft, so the "bins" are in two rows.  Let's number them as:

```
0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
```

We want to arrange different plants in each one. Each plant has some buddies that they like to be near. For example, basil likes to be near tomatoes. I want to find an arrangement for the garden that maximizes the number of positive relationships.

Using python, it's easy to shove the different crops in a list. It's also easy to make a scoring function to find the total score for a particular arrangement. My problem is reducing the problem size. In this setup, there are 8! (40,320) possible permutations, different arrangements of plants in the garden. In the real one I'm trying to solve, I'm using a 16-bin garden, twice the size. That's 16! possible permutations to go through, over 20 trillion. It's taking too long. (I've described the problem here with 8 bins instead of 16 to simplify.)

I've used itertools.permutations to run through all the possible permutations of 8 items. However, it doesn't know enough to skip arrangements that are essentially duplicates. If I rotate a garden arrangement by 180 degrees, it's really the same solution. If I mirror left-to-right or up-and-down, they're also the same solutions. How can I set this up to reduce the total problem set?

In other problems, I've used lookups to check through a list of solutions already checked. With this large number of solutions, that would consume more time than simply going through all of them. Please help me reduce the problem set!

```
# maximize the number of good relationships in a garden
import itertools

# each crop has 2 items: the name of the crop and a list of all the good friends
crops = []
crops.append(['basil',['tomato','pepper','lettuce']]) # basil likes to be near tomato, pepper or lettuce
crops.append(['strawberry',['beans','lettuce']])
crops.append(['beans',['beet','marigold','cucumber','potato','strawberry','radish']])
crops.append(['beet',['beans']])
crops.append(['cucumber',['lettuce','radish','tomato','dill','marigold']])
crops.append(['marigold',['tomato','cucumber','potato','beans']])
crops.append(['tomato',['cucumber','chives','marigold','basil','dill']])
crops.append(['bok_choy',['dill']])

# 0 1 2 3 This is what the garden looks like, with 8 bins
# 4 5 6 7
mates = [ [0,1], [1,2], [2,3], [4,5], [5,6], [6,7], [0,4], [1,5], [2,6], [3,7] ] # these are the relationships that directly border one another

def score(c): # A scoring function that returns the number of good relationships
    s = 0
    for pair in mates:
        for j in c[pair[1]][1]:
            if c[pair[0]][0] == j:
                s = s + 1
        for j in c[pair[0]][1]: # and the revers, 1-0
            if c[pair[1]][0] == j:
                s = s + 1
    return s

scoremax = 0
for x in itertools.permutations(crops,8):
    s = score(x)
    if s >= scoremax: # show the arrangement
        for i in range(0,4):
            print( x[i][0] + ' ' * (12-len(x[i][0])) + x[i+4][0] + ' ' * (12-len(x[i+4][0])) ) # print to screen
        print(s)
        print('')
        if s > scoremax:
            scoremax = s
```

EDIT: To clarify, these are the symmetry and rotation arrangements I'm trying to skip. For clarity, I'll use numbers instead of the plant name strings.

```
0 1 2 3 is same when mirrored 3 2 1 0
4 5 6 7                       7 6 5 4

0 1 2 3 is same when mirrored 4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7                       0 1 2 3

0 1 2 3 is same when rotated  7 6 5 4
4 5 6 7                       3 2 1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is often very difficult to efficiently break symmetries for this kind of problems.

In this case, there seem to be just 2 symmetries:

- right to left is the same as left to right
- up to down is the same as down to up

We can break both of them if we add three conditions:

> the crop at plot 0 should both be smaller than the crop at plot 3 and the one  at plot 4 and the one at plot 7

For 'smaller' we can use any measure that gives a strict ordering. In this case we can simply compare the strings.

The main loop would then look as follows. Once the optimal `scoremax` is reached, only solutions that don't have symmetry will be printed. Also, every possible solution will either be printed directly or will be printed in its canonical form (i.e. mirrored horizontally and/or vertically).

```py
# maximize the number of good relationships in a garden
import itertools

# each crop has 2 items: the name of the crop and a list of all the good friends
crops = []
crops.append(['basil',['tomato','pepper','lettuce']]) # basil likes to be near tomato, pepper or lettuce
crops.append(['strawberry',['beans','lettuce']])
crops.append(['beans',['beet','marigold','cucumber','potato','strawberry','radish']])
crops.append(['beet',['beans']])
crops.append(['cucumber',['lettuce','radish','tomato','dill','marigold']])
crops.append(['marigold',['tomato','cucumber','potato','beans']])
crops.append(['tomato',['cucumber','chives','marigold','basil','dill']])
crops.append(['bok_choy',['dill']])

# 0 1 2 3 This is what the garden looks like, with 8 bins
# 4 5 6 7
mates = [ [0,1], [1,2], [2,3], [4,5], [5,6], [6,7], [0,4], [1,5], [2,6], [3,7] ] # these are the relationships that directly border one another

def score(c): # A scoring function that returns the number of good relationships
    s = 0
    for pair in mates:
        for j in c[pair[1]][1]:
            if c[pair[0]][0] == j:
                s = s + 1
        for j in c[pair[0]][1]: # and the revers, 1-0
            if c[pair[1]][0] == j:
                s = s + 1
    return s

scoremax = 0
for x in itertools.permutations(crops,8):
    if x[0][0] < x[3][0] and x[0][0] < x[4][0] and x[0][0] < x[7][0]:
        s = score(x)
        if s >= scoremax: # show the arrangement
            for i in range(0,4):
                print( x[i][0] + ' ' * (12-len(x[i][0])) + x[i+4][0] + ' ' * (12-len(x[i+4][0])) ) # print to screen
            print(s)
            print('')
            if s > scoremax:
                scoremax = s
```

Comment: No, your check is looking if the same crop name is in two different positions -- if the arrangement itself is a mirror. There are no mirrors like that, as I have a unique crop in each bin. What it can really look for is whether past permutations were already run, and if they are a mirror of the current one. Sadly, in this case, that kind of lookup would be *more* expensive than just evaluating the score, because there are so many.

Comment: Did you try to run it? Didn't it get the desired output?

Comment: Do, I did not run your code suggestion. 1, that would skip all, because strings can't be less than one another. 'basil' < 'tomato' isn't a thing. 2, though the code isn't perfect, I assumed you meant to do a symmetry check, like check and see if it's 'basil','tomato','tomato','basil' in one row. As I said, the permuations of 8 unique objects in 8 bins never matches that symmetry check.

Comment: Well, in Python 'basil' < 'tomato' really is a thing. My code does work as intended. It copes with horizontal and vertical mirroring and with rotation of 180 degrees. The symmetry check controls that only 'basil' at the top left and 'tomato' at the top right is considered, but never 'tomato' at the top left and 'basil' at the top right.